# CakePHP - How do I join a table on a joined table?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am in the FilesController and I'm trying to get a file based on the condition that its order belongs to the current user.

**FilesController**

```
// Check the file exists and that it belongs to the user

$this->File->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'File.id' => $id,
        'Order.Customer.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    ),
    'recursive' => 2
));
```

**Cake SQL Error**

```
Unknown column 'Order.Customer.id' in 'where clause'
```

I'm trying to get the SQL to left join `orders` onto `files` and then left join `customers` onto `orders`, but I can't figure out how to join the customers table, although I'm sure I've done this before.  I've tried everything I can think of with the conditions, and using `contains`.

Here's my model relationships:

**Customer Model**

```
class Customer extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array('Order');

}
```

**Order Model**

```
class Order extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Customer');

    public $hasMany = array('File');

}
```

**File Model**

```
class File extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Order');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised there is no need to actually join the customers table in this instance, because the orders table already has the customer_id.

```
$this->File->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'File.id' => $id,
        'Order.customer_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the tables using the 'joins' parameter. Sometimes 'contains' doesn't work and you need to fall back on this.

```
$this->File->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'File.id' => $id,
        'Order.Customer_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'orders',
            'alias' => 'Order',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('File.orders_id = Order.id')
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'customers',
            'alias' => 'Customer',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Customer.orders_id = Order.id')
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Containable (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) as it is the easiest solution. You can not use Order.Customer.id as Cake does not nest conditions like that. Manual joins would also work.

Comment: Do you have an examples?  I couldn't get anything to work with `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->loadModel('Customer');
$customer = $this->Customer->findById($this->Auth->user('id'), array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'File.id' => $id
        ),
        'recursive' => 2
    ));
```

Orders will be accessible as:

```
pr($customer['Order']);
```

File will be accessible as:

```
pr($customer['File']);
```